# Update elements within Nested Xml

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq-to-xml

I have Xml which looks like this:

```
<DataMapper xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <SqlTable />
  <Level_01s>
    <DataParameter>
      <SqlTable>MY-Table-Name</SqlTable>
      <Children>
        <DataParameter>
          <SqlTable>MY-Table-Name</SqlTable>
          <Children>
            <DataParameter>
              <SqlTable>MY-Table-Name</SqlTable>
              <Children>
                <DataParameter>
                  <SqlTable>[All]</SqlTable>
                  <Children />
                </DataParameter>
                <DataParameter>
                  <SqlTable>MY-Table-Name</SqlTable>
                  <Children>
                    <DataParameter>
                      <SqlTable>[All]</SqlTable>
                      <Children />
                    </DataParameter>
                  </Children>
                </DataParameter>
              </Children>
            </DataParameter>
          </Children>
        </DataParameter>
      </Children>
    </DataParameter>
  </Level_01s>
</ DataMapper>
```

What I'd like to do is update all instances of the  element. The issue that I have is that the DataParameters may go n-levels deep.

How can I recursivly ensure I update all of these?

I am using this code to update Root-level elements:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(myxmlstring);
var element = xdoc.Elements("SqlTable").Single();
element.Value = "foo";        
xdoc.Save("file.xml");
```

via [Best way to change the value of an element in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/544310/best-way-to-change-the-value-of-an-element-in-c)

Comment: I updated my answer to show how you can provide a predicate in the statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use Descendants("SqlTable") instead of Elements("SqlTable").Single() it will get you all of the "SQLTable" elements in the entire document.  Then you can just foreach through them and update the elements.

```
var elements = xdoc.Descendants("SqlTable");

foreach (var sqlTable in elements)
{
    sqlTable.Value = "foo";
}
```

Or if you want to be terse you can do it all in LINQ syntax

**Updated based on comment**, Added .Where with predicate to build the list as an example of using a condition.

```
xdoc.Descendants("SqlTable").Where(s => s.Value != "All").ToList().ForEach(p => p.Value = "foo");
```

Comment: How could I use the LINQ syntax but provide a conditional? (p => p.Value = "foo") only if p.Value != "All"?

Comment: I had to change .All(s => s.Value != "All") to .Where(s => s.Value != "All") but it worked great! thanks!