# Update a single element of a xml serialized by DataContractserializer in C#?

Tags: c#, datacontractserializer

I have a class, which is serialized using the `DataContractSerializer` class. Now I want to update a single property (a string) of the serialized object.

For some reason, I can't find a functionality for this, so my only option would be to serialize the complete object - which can get quite big. It seems a bit of overkill to serialize several hundreds of lines just to change a single string element.
Is there no better approach to this?

Comment: You are using a Data Contract which uses Xml Serialization.  You can load the xml using other  Net Libraries and then parse file and change one item.  I prefer using the Xml Linq library to do this.

Comment: @jdweng Thanks, but I tried to use the `XDocument` and `XmlDocument` class, both of which wouldn't work - meaning they wouldn't find the needed Element. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/544310/best-way-to-change-the-value-of-an-element-in-c-sharp/32027344](I used this method.). I thought the problem was, that for exampl a property called `Name` is saved with a tag prefix like `d2p1:Name` (I think, not currently on the machine). Maybe I have to define a custom Name for the item...

Comment: I've use XDocument a lot and always able to find a tag.  If you are not finding a tag it either means you need a namespace or the tag is a descendent and not a Element.  Check Xml to see if there is a default namespace xmlns="URL" ( a namespace with no prefix

Comment: @jdweng Hmm, I think you pointed me to the issue. I'll test it out, thanks! :)