# Best way to read xml

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xpath, xmlreader

What's best way to read XML ?

My xml is like that
I'll have a lot of

```
<A> and <B>, not sure how many will be there and I have to read the whole xml file.
```

I can not say that the child element like

```
<180> will be there under <A> for sure. So does the other element.
```

But if it's there I have to read it.

**Should I use LINQ or XPath or XMLReader ?** Which one will be better and easier?

```
        <A>
            <180>20130218</180>  ///180 is here
            <170>5</170>
            <220>20080210</220>
            <730 CLID='AAA' KW='BBB' KW2='INTERNATIONAL'>
                <731>BBB INTERNATIONAL AG</731>
                <732>XXX</732>
                <735>US66</735>
                <734>YYY</734>
            </730>
            <300>
                <301>
                    <320>20071100</320>
                    <310>12345</310>
                </301>
                <330>US</330>
            </300>
        </A>
        <A>                    ///180 is not here
            <170>5</170>
            <220>20080210</220>
            <730 CLID='AAA' KW='BBB' KW2='WORLD'>
                <731>BBB INTERNATIONAL AG</731>
                <734>YYY</734>
            </730>
            <300>
                <301>
                    <320>20071100</320>
                    <310>12345</310>
                </301>
                <330>UK</330>
            </300>
        </A>
        <B>
            <180>20130218</180>
            <170>5</170>
            <220>20080210</220>
            <730 CLID='AAA' KW='BBB' KW2='INTERNATIONAL'>
                <731>BBB INTERNATIONAL AG</731>
                <732>XXX</732>
                <733>JP</733>
                <735>JP66</735>
                <734>YYY</734>
            </730>
            <300>
                <301>
                    <320>20071100</320>
                    <310>12345</310>
                </301>
                <330>JP</330>
            </300>
        </B>
```

Comment: What you use depends upon what you wish to achieve. If you are simply reading the content, fopen() is also sufficient.

Comment: What do you want to read? How big will the XML be? Can it fit into memory? Which XML parser to use would depend on answers to those questions.

Comment: may I ask you what you're supposed to do with this XML? I mean, convert it to Domain Model Object, or what else?
Is the element structures known, except for A and B tags? I mean, <301> will always be under <300>?

Comment: XML can be as large as 150 KB. I want to save the data in database.

Comment: 301 will be always under 300 but it's not always sure to exist.

Comment: This question has been asked: [What is the best way to parse (big) XML in C# Code?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676274/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-big-xml-in-c-sharp-code

Comment: What you have provided as "XML" isn't a welformed XML document at all. Processing it with XML tools most probably will raise errors. More specifically, an element name cannot start with a digit. Therefore, all tags like `<300>` will cause errors to be produced.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Should I use LINQ or XPath or XMLReader ? Which one will be better and easier?

XDocument (Linq-to-XML) will be the easiest. And it can probably do what you want but you should be clearer about the desired outcome.

> XML can be as large as 150 KB.

No problem at all. Only start to consider XmlReader when you reach 150 MB.