# Read only root-element from XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, xmldocument

I have a very large xml-file (let's say it has about 300000 elements). In my part of the application I only have to know if the name of the root-element is `ApplicationLog` and if there is an attribute called `LogId` in the root-element.

To read the XML I use:

```
XDocument document;
using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(filePath, true))
{   
    document = XDocument.Load(streamReader);
}
```

and to get the information I need:

```
try
{
    if (document.Root != null)
    {       
        if (string.Equals(document.Root.Name.LocalName, "ApplicationLog", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) &&
            document.Root.HasAttributes && (from o in document.Root.Attributes() where string.Equals(o.Name.LocalName, "LogId", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) select o).Any())
        {
            isRelevantFile = true;
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
}
```

This just works fine.

The problem is that the `XDocument.Load` takes about 15 seconds to load a XML-File which is about 20MB.

I also tried it with the `XmlDocument`, but there I have the same problem.

My first idea for a solution was to read the file as text and parse the first lines for the searched element/attribute. But this seems to be not so professional to me.

Does anybody know a better way to achieve this?

Comment: If you have a solution that is simple AND works, how can it not be professional?

Answer (score 4):

Use the `XmlReader` API with

```
using (XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(filePath))
{
  xr.MoveToContent();
  if (xr.LocalName == "ApplicationLog" ...)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/676280/3021830) or use/develop a SAX reader such as [this one](http://saxdotnet.sourceforge.net/). You can find more information on SAX [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_API_for_XML#XML_processing_with_SAX).