# Custom List<MyObject> constructor

Tags: c#, windows, list

I created my class with a couple of properties.

And i was trying to use the List and create a constructor to send an object and have it creating the list with all the objects.

```
    public class List<MyObject>
    {
       public List<MyObject>(object x)
       {
           //Do Things here
       }   
    }
```

Is this possible?

Comment: do not reinvent the wheel

Comment: What this pseudocode should mean? It will not even be compiled.

Comment: it is possible with `public List(object x)` .ctor syntax instead of `public List<MyObject>(object x)`

Comment: As it is now it is unclear what you're asking (at least to me). Please edit your question, try to explain what problem would be solved by having this available to you...   And btw welcome to SO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would not be better to inherit List<>

for example :

```
   class InheritClass : List<ITest>
{
    public InheritClass(object parameter)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
class test
{
    public test()
    {
        InheritClass a = new InheritClass(new object());
        a.Add(new ITest);
    }
}
```

Comment: I could do that, but i dont know if i will need to extend all the methods like add and remove. Does it still work like the default ones?

Comment: Yes, you dont next to extent those method base `List` class provide you default functionally for it, just for your couple of properties this kind of defination for your class required

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyObject : List<IListType>
{
   public MyObject(object x)
   {
       //Do Things here
   }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do this ?

1. The list itself can take a 1..n of objects to create a list for you.
2. You could use an Collection Initializer like: new List {1,2,3}

If you're looking for a means to create a list based on some domain requirements, I would look at Factorial patterns.

Comment: I needed this because i want to transform an xmlNode object to a list of this custom object.

Comment: You could simply do this using Lambda actually.

Comment: I guess i could, but i was trying to do this as efficient as possible.

Comment: xmlNodeList.Select(x => new Object { PropA = x.ProbB } ).ToList() // The most simple solution in Lambda terms.

Comment: Yes, true deferred execution...  However, I don't think by "gut feeling" this is where your optimization should be (if your xml source is large)

Comment: To be completly honest with you my xml size will be determined by real life events so i dont really know what i am expecting in terms of size.

Comment: Okay, so with XML your main issue is not the transformation of objects, but size in memory. Please have a look at this post too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676274/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-big-xml-in-c-sharp-code