Efficient way to extract two fields from large XML file in C#
I want to extract from a large English to German dictionary XML file where the structure looks like:
      <entry xml:id="Ais.1">
        <form>
          <orth>Ais</orth>
        </form>
        <gramGrp>
          <gen>neut</gen>
          <pos>n</pos>
          <number>sg</number>
        </gramGrp>
        <sense>
          <cit type="trans">
            <quote xml:lang="en">A</quote>
            <gramGrp>
              <pos>n</pos>
            </gramGrp>
          </cit>
...

The English word is inside <orth> </orth> and I'm happy to take the first German word, inside <quote> </quote>.  The source XML file is 500MB big. I want to store the output in a non-xml file that has format: englishWord : germanWord per line.  I exclude multiple word entries in orth or in quote.
My C# code is:
  string fileStr = File.ReadAllText( @"C:\deu-eng.xml" );
  int quoteTagLength = "<quote xml: lang=\"en\">".Length;
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  int currIndex = 0;
  bool foundSomething = true;
  while (foundSomething)
  {
    foundSomething = false;       
    int i = fileStr.IndexOf( "<orth>", currIndex );
    if (i > 0)  // found something
    {
      int i2 = fileStr.IndexOf( "</orth>", i + 6 );

      currIndex = i2 + 1;
      int qi = fileStr.IndexOf( "<quote xml:lang=\"en\">", currIndex );
      if (qi > 0)
      {
        int qi2 = fileStr.IndexOf( "</quote>", qi + 8 );
        if (qi2 > 0)
        {
          string word1 = fileStr.Substring( i + 6, i2 - (i + 6) );
          string word2 = fileStr.Substring( qi + quoteTagLength - 1, qi2 - (qi + quoteTagLength) ) + 1;
         
          if (!word1.Contains( " " ) && !word2.Contains( " " ))
          {
            sb.Append( word1  + " : " + word2 + Environment.NewLine );
          }
          foundSomething = true;
      }
    }
   }
  }

But this runs slowly.  How can I optimize this?
My method should be faster already than any method using XMLReader, since it only moves forward and only needs pairs of two types of fields, and can safely ignore nesting levels so does not need a stack.  But I feel it should be more efficient than it is.

https://stackoverflow.com/q/676274/2834978

"My method should be faster already than any method using XMLReader" You think you can write a faster parser than Microsoft can? Dream on.

Nost definitely, since I don't need to use a stack and traverse a tree structure and store every field.  I have a much simpler requirement for values extracted from the XML, which allows me to do it more efficiently.  Imagine you need to see if there is a single red pixel in an image.  Someone may suggest using a neural network or convolutional algo or transform, but I would just search for a red pixel.  Same idea.   Why use a method that is inherently more complex  and expensive when a simple one will do.

The XmlReader class has many useful methods, such as ReadToFollowing and ReadSubtree. With them, the final code will be very concise and at the same time effective.

But in theory it should always be slower than my code above, because XMLReader would be doing more work... the question is what optimizations can I do?  I thought of putting the strings in const string declarations outside the loops so it does not access the string pool in the loop.

I tried using XMLReader and it does the whole thing in about a second, so yes much faster.  I'd still like to know where my algo was slow :/

"<quote xml: lang=\"en\">".Length - do you see whitespace before lang? I suppose it's a typo. But this shows the essence of the possible problems well: XML can contain whitespace characters in different places in any number. And a simple text search can break down because of this.

word1  + " : " + word2 + Environment.NewLine - here string allocations occurs. Use multiple Append calls instead. You should also allocate memory in advance in the constructor: new StringBuilder(10_000_000).
