# Deserializing xml feed fails invalid hexadecimal character

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I've read a few other posts on this, but I'm not able to achieve what I'm looking to do.

- [XML deserialization fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355995/xml-deserialization-fail)

Here's my current method for deserializing data

```
public static T Deserialize<T>(string serializedString)
{
    using (Stream s = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(serializedString)))
    {
        var serXml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        T item = (T)serXml.Deserialize(s);
        return item;
    }
}
```

The problem is that I'm getting an invalid character failure.

> System.Xml.XmlException: '', hexadecimal value 0x0B, is an invalid character.

I have no control over the vimeo feed, so I need to be able to appropriately deserialize the string on my end. Am I missing something silly?

*note: I have been looking into XmlTextReader, but I've read that it shouldn't be used.*

#### EDIT

---

Here's the XML as formatted from Vimeo contained in the `serializedString` parameter

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<videos>
    <!-- hacked out a few videos from when they worked.
         StackOverflow was complaining about the length of the post -->
<video><id>35524605</id><title>A Year of Success: Work</title><description>Series: A Year of Success&lt;br /&gt;
Sermon: Work&lt;br /&gt;
Speaker: Geoff Heth&lt;br /&gt;
Scripture: John 13&lt;br /&gt;
Date: January 21 &amp; 22, 2012</description><url>http://vimeo.com/35524605</url><upload_date>2012-01-23 14:10:00</upload_date><mobile_url>http://vimeo.com/m/35524605</mobile_url><thumbnail_small>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/242/906/242906651_100.jpg</thumbnail_small><thumbnail_medium>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/242/906/242906651_200.jpg</thumbnail_medium><thumbnail_large>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/242/906/242906651_640.jpg</thumbnail_large><user_name>RockPointe Church</user_name><user_url>http://vimeo.com/rockpointe</user_url><user_portrait_small>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ps/196/827/1968276_30.jpg</user_portrait_small><user_portrait_medium>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ps/196/827/1968276_75.jpg</user_portrait_medium><user_portrait_large>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ps/196/827/1968276_100.jpg</user_portrait_large><user_portrait_huge>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ps/196/827/1968276_300.jpg</user_portrait_huge><stats_number_of_likes>0</stats_number_of_likes><stats_number_of_plays>60</stats_number_of_plays><stats_number_of_comments>0</stats_number_of_comments><duration>2227</duration><width>1280</width><height>720</height><tags>a year of success, work, geoff heth, john 13, january 21, january 22</tags><embed_privacy>anywhere</embed_privacy></video><video><id>35149699</id><title>A Year of Success: Spirituality</title><description>Series: A Year of Success&lt;br /&gt;
Sermon: Spirituality&lt;br /&gt;
Speaker: Tim Moore&lt;br /&gt;
Scripture: John 15&lt;br /&gt;
Date: January 14 &amp; 15, 2012</description><url>http://vimeo.com/35149699</url><upload_date>2012-01-16 12:38:23</upload_date><mobile_url>http://vimeo.com/m/35149699</mobile_url><thumbnail_small>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/239/968/239968893_100.jpg</thumbnail_small><thumbnail_medium>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/239/968/239968893_200.jpg</thumbnail_medium><thumbnail_large>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/239/968/239968893_640.jpg</thumbnail_large><user_name>RockPointe Church</user_name><user_url>http://vimeo.com/rockpointe</user_url><user_portrait_small>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ps/196/827/1968276_30.jpg</user_portrait_small><user_portrait_medium>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ps/196/827/1968276_75.jpg</user_portrait_medium><user_portrait_large>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ps/196/827/1968276_100.jpg</user_portrait_large><user_portrait_huge>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ps/196/827/1968276_300.jpg</user_portrait_huge><stats_number_of_likes>0</stats_number_of_likes><stats_number_of_plays>43</stats_number_of_plays><stats_number_of_comments>0</stats_number_of_comments><duration>2871</duration><width>1280</width><height>720</height><tags>a year of success, spirituality, tim moore, john 15, january 15, January 14</tags><embed_privacy>anywhere</embed_privacy></video><video><id>34789964</id><title>A Year of Success: Relationships</title><description>Series: A Year of Success&lt;br /&gt;
Sermon: Relationships&lt;br /&gt;
Speaker: Ron Gray&lt;br /&gt;
Scripture: John 13:34,35&lt;br /&gt;
Date: January 7 &amp; 8, 2012</description><url>http://vimeo.com/34789964</url><upload_date>2012-01-09 11:15:53</upload_date><mobile_url>http://vimeo.com/m/34789964</mobile_url><thumbnail_small>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/237/215/237215947_100.jpg</thumbnail_small><thumbnail_medium>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/237/215/237215947_200.jpg</thumbnail_medium><thumbnail_large>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/237/215/237215947_640.jpg</thumbnail_large><user_name>RockPointe Church</user_name><user_url>http://vimeo.com/rockpointe</user_url><user_portrait_small>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ps/196/827/1968276_30.jpg</user_portrait_small><user_portrait_medium>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ps/196/827/1968276_75.jpg</user_portrait_medium><user_portrait_large>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ps/196/827/1968276_100.jpg</user_portrait_large><user_portrait_huge>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ps/196/827/1968276_300.jpg</user_portrait_huge><stats_number_of_likes>0</stats_number_of_likes><stats_number_of_plays>76</stats_number_of_plays><stats_number_of_comments>0</stats_number_of_comments><duration>2128</duration><width>1280</width><height>720</height><tags>John 13, January 7, January 8, A year of success, relationships, ron gray</tags><embed_privacy>anywhere</embed_privacy></video><video><id>33914231</id><title>When God Broke In: The Shepherds</title><description>Series: When God Broke In&lt;br /&gt;
Sermon: The Shepherds&lt;br /&gt;
Speaker: Geoff Heth&lt;br /&gt;
Scripture: Luke 2:8-20&lt;br /&gt;
Date: December 17 &amp; 18&lt;br /&gt;
&lt;br /&gt;
BIG IDEA:God again announces His love for all of us and gives us hope for the future.</description><url>http://vimeo.com/33914231</url><upload_date>2011-12-19 11:14:25</upload_date><mobile_url>http://vimeo.com/m/33914231</mobile_url><thumbnail_small>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/230/541/230541509_100.jpg</thumbnail_small><thumbnail_medium>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/230/541/230541509_200.jpg</thumbnail_medium><thumbnail_large>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/230/541/230541509_640.jpg</thumbnail_large><user_name>RockPointe Church</user_name><user_url>http://vimeo.com/rockpointe</user_url><user_portrait_small>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ps/196/827/1968276_30.jpg</user_portrait_small><user_portrait_medium>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ps/196/827/1968276_75.jpg</user_portrait_medium><user_portrait_large>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ps/196/827/1968276_100.jpg</user_portrait_large><user_portrait_huge>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ps/196/827/1968276_300.jpg</user_portrait_huge><stats_number_of_likes>0</stats_number_of_likes><stats_number_of_plays>87</stats_number_of_plays><stats_number_of_comments>0</stats_number_of_comments><duration>2076</duration><width>1280</width><height>720</height><tags>When God Broke In, Shepherds, Geoff Heth, Luke, December 17, December 18</tags><embed_privacy>anywhere</embed_privacy></video><video><id>33540401</id><title>When God Broke In: Mary &amp; Joseph</title><description>Series: When God Broke In&lt;br /&gt;
Sermon: Mary &amp; Joseph&lt;br /&gt;
Speaker: Ron Gray&lt;br /&gt;
Scripture: Luke 1:26-38; Matthew 1:18-25&lt;br /&gt;
Date: December 10 &amp; 11, 2011</description><url>http://vimeo.com/33540401</url><upload_date>2011-12-12 11:26:54</upload_date><mobile_url>http://vimeo.com/m/33540401</mobile_url><thumbnail_small>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/227/715/227715871_100.jpg</thumbnail_small><thumbnail_medium>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/227/715/227715871_200.jpg</thumbnail_medium><thumbnail_large>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/227/715/227715871_640.jpg</thumbnail_large><user_name>RockPointe Church</user_name><user_url>http://vimeo.com/rockpointe</user_url><user_portrait_small>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ps/196/827/1968276_30.jpg</user_portrait_small><user_portrait_medium>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ps/196/827/1968276_75.jpg</user_portrait_medium><user_portrait_large>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ps/196/827/1968276_100.jpg</user_portrait_large><user_portrait_huge>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ps/196/827/1968276_300.jpg</user_portrait_huge><stats_number_of_likes>0</stats_number_of_likes><stats_number_of_plays>47</stats_number_of_plays><stats_number_of_comments>0</stats_number_of_comments><duration>2119</duration><width>1280</width><height>720</height><tags>When God Broke In, Mary, Joseph, Ron Gray, Luke, Matthew, December 10, December 11</tags><embed_privacy>anywhere</embed_privacy></video><video><id>33168687</id><title>When God Broke In: Zechariah</title><description>Series: When God Broke In&lt;br /&gt;
Sermon: Zechariah&lt;br /&gt;
Speaker: Erik McRitchie&lt;br /&gt;
Scripture: Luke 1:5-25, 57-80&lt;br /&gt;
Date: December 3 &amp; 4, 2011</description><url>http://vimeo.com/33168687</url><upload_date>2011-12-05 12:45:36</upload_date><mobile_url>http://vimeo.com/m/33168687</mobile_url><thumbnail_small>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/224/927/224927953_100.jpg</thumbnail_small><thumbnail_medium>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/224/927/224927953_200.jpg</thumbnail_medium><thumbnail_large>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/224/927/224927953_640.jpg</thumbnail_large><user_name>RockPointe Church</user_name><user_url>http://vimeo.com/rockpointe</user_url><user_portrait_small>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ps/196/827/1968276_30.jpg</user_portrait_small><user_portrait_medium>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ps/196/827/1968276_75.jpg</user_portrait_medium><user_portrait_large>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ps/196/827/1968276_100.jpg</user_portrait_large><user_portrait_huge>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ps/196/827/1968276_300.jpg</user_portrait_huge><stats_number_of_likes>0</stats_number_of_likes><stats_number_of_plays>72</stats_number_of_plays><stats_number_of_comments>0</stats_number_of_comments><duration>1819</duration><width>1280</width><height>720</height><tags>When God Broke In, Zechariah, Erik McRitchie, Luke, December 3, December 4</tags><embed_privacy>anywhere</embed_privacy></video><video><id>32791671</id><title>Made Right - Romans: Kingdom Rules Part 3</title><description>Series: Made Right - Romans &lt;br /&gt;
Sermon: Kingdom Rules pt. 3&lt;br /&gt;
Speaker: Ron Gray, Brian Delamont&lt;br /&gt;
Scripture: Romans 14-15&lt;br /&gt;
Date: November 26 &amp; 27</description><url>http://vimeo.com/32791671</url><upload_date>2011-11-28 11:35:27</upload_date><mobile_url>http://vimeo.com/m/32791671</mobile_url><thumbnail_small>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/222/079/222079267_100.jpg</thumbnail_small><thumbnail_medium>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/222/079/222079267_200.jpg</thumbnail_medium><thumbnail_large>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/222/079/222079267_640.jpg</thumbnail_large><user_name>RockPointe Church</user_name><user_url>http://vimeo.com/rockpointe</user_url><user_portrait_small>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ps/196/827/1968276_30.jpg</user_portrait_small><user_portrait_medium>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ps/196/827/1968276_75.jpg</user_portrait_medium><user_portrait_large>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ps/196/827/1968276_100.jpg</user_portrait_large><user_portrait_huge>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ps/196/827/1968276_300.jpg</user_portrait_huge><stats_number_of_likes>0</stats_number_of_likes><stats_number_of_plays>26</stats_number_of_plays><stats_number_of_comments>0</stats_number_of_comments><duration>527</duration><width>1280</width><height>720</height><tags>Made Right, Romans, Kingdom Rules, Ron Gray, Brian Delamont, November 26, November 27</tags><embed_privacy>anywhere</embed_privacy></video><video><id>32791416</id><title>Made Right - Romans: Kingdom Rules Part 2</title><description>Series: Made Right - Romans &lt;br /&gt;
Sermon: Kingdom Rules pt. 2&lt;br /&gt;
Speaker: Ron Gray, Brian Delamont&lt;br /&gt;
Scripture: Romans 14-15&lt;br /&gt;
Date: November 26 &amp; 27</description><url>http://vimeo.com/32791416</url><upload_date>2011-11-28 11:31:07</upload_date><mobile_url>http://vimeo.com/m/32791416</mobile_url><thumbnail_small>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/222/076/222076112_100.jpg</thumbnail_small><thumbnail_medium>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/222/076/222076112_200.jpg</thumbnail_medium><thumbnail_large>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/222/076/222076112_640.jpg</thumbnail_large><user_name>RockPointe Church</user_name><user_url>http://vimeo.com/rockpointe</user_url><user_portrait_small>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ps/196/827/1968276_30.jpg</user_portrait_small><user_portrait_medium>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ps/196/827/1968276_75.jpg</user_portrait_medium><user_portrait_large>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ps/196/827/1968276_100.jpg</user_portrait_large><user_portrait_huge>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ps/196/827/1968276_300.jpg</user_portrait_huge><stats_number_of_likes>0</stats_number_of_likes><stats_number_of_plays>13</stats_number_of_plays><stats_number_of_comments>0</stats_number_of_comments><duration>591</duration><width>1280</width><height>720</height><tags>Made Right, Kingdom Rules, Ron Gray, Brian Delamont, Romans, November 26, November 27</tags><embed_privacy>anywhere</embed_privacy></video><video><id>32792125</id><title>Made Right - Romans: Kingdom Rules Part 1</title><description>Series: Made Right - Romans&lt;br /&gt;
Sermon: Kingdom Rules&lt;br /&gt;
Speaker: Ron Gray, Brian Delamont&lt;br /&gt;
Scripture: Romans 14-15&lt;br /&gt;
Date: November 26 &amp; 27, 2011</description><url>http://vimeo.com/32792125</url><upload_date>2011-11-28 11:43:13</upload_date><mobile_url>http://vimeo.com/m/32792125</mobile_url><thumbnail_small>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/222/082/222082190_100.jpg</thumbnail_small><thumbnail_medium>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/222/082/222082190_200.jpg</thumbnail_medium><thumbnail_large>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/222/082/222082190_640.jpg</thumbnail_large><user_name>RockPointe Church</user_name><user_url>http://vimeo.com/rockpointe</user_url><user_portrait_small>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ps/196/827/1968276_30.jpg</user_portrait_small><user_portrait_medium>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ps/196/827/1968276_75.jpg</user_portrait_medium><user_portrait_large>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ps/196/827/1968276_100.jpg</user_portrait_large><user_portrait_huge>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ps/196/827/1968276_300.jpg</user_portrait_huge><stats_number_of_likes>0</stats_number_of_likes><stats_number_of_plays>28</stats_number_of_plays><stats_number_of_comments>0</stats_number_of_comments><duration>946</duration><width>1280</width><height>720</height><tags>Made Right, Kingdom Rules, Ron Gray, Brian Delamont, Romans, November 26, November 27</tags><embed_privacy>anywhere</embed_privacy></video><video><id>32453817</id><title>Made Right - Romans: Submission</title><description>Series: Made Right - Romans&lt;br /&gt;
Sermon: Submission&lt;br /&gt;
Speaker: Jason Koleba&lt;br /&gt;
Scripture: Romans 13&lt;br /&gt;
Date: November 19 &amp; 20, 2011&lt;br /&gt;
&lt;br /&gt;
The BIG idea: Our ability to make an impact as leaders and as a church, rests not only with our readiness to lead, do things and be proactive, but also in our ability to  humbly submit.</description><url>http://vimeo.com/32453817</url><upload_date>2011-11-21 10:55:06</upload_date><mobile_url>http://vimeo.com/m/32453817</mobile_url><thumbnail_small>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/219/552/219552106_100.jpg</thumbnail_small><thumbnail_medium>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/219/552/219552106_200.jpg</thumbnail_medium><thumbnail_large>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/219/552/219552106_640.jpg</thumbnail_large><user_name>RockPointe Church</user_name><user_url>http://vimeo.com/rockpointe</user_url><user_portrait_small>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ps/196/827/1968276_30.jpg</user_portrait_small><user_portrait_medium>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ps/196/827/1968276_75.jpg</user_portrait_medium><user_portrait_large>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ps/196/827/1968276_100.jpg</user_portrait_large><user_portrait_huge>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ps/196/827/1968276_300.jpg</user_portrait_huge><stats_number_of_likes>0</stats_number_of_likes><stats_number_of_plays>22</stats_number_of_plays><stats_number_of_comments>0</stats_number_of_comments><duration>2106</duration><width>1280</width><height>720</height><tags>Made Right, Romans, Submission, Jason Koleba, Romans 13, November 19</tags><embed_privacy>anywhere</embed_privacy></video><video><id>32090108</id><title>Made Right - Romans: We Are Family</title><description>Series: Made Right - Romans&lt;br /&gt;
Sermon: We Are Family&lt;br /&gt;
Speaker: Brent Sellers&lt;br /&gt;
Scripture: Romans 12&lt;br /&gt;
Date: November 12, 2011</description><url>http://vimeo.com/32090108</url><upload_date>2011-11-14 11:09:27</upload_date><mobile_url>http://vimeo.com/m/32090108</mobile_url><thumbnail_small>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/216/803/216803372_100.jpg</thumbnail_small><thumbnail_medium>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/216/803/216803372_200.jpg</thumbnail_medium><thumbnail_large>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/216/803/216803372_640.jpg</thumbnail_large><user_name>RockPointe Church</user_name><user_url>http://vimeo.com/rockpointe</user_url><user_portrait_small>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ps/196/827/1968276_30.jpg</user_portrait_small><user_portrait_medium>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ps/196/827/1968276_75.jpg</user_portrait_medium><user_portrait_large>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ps/196/827/1968276_100.jpg</user_portrait_large><user_portrait_huge>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ps/196/827/1968276_300.jpg</user_portrait_huge><stats_number_of_likes>0</stats_number_of_likes><stats_number_of_plays>96</stats_number_of_plays><stats_number_of_comments>0</stats_number_of_comments><duration>2146</duration><width>1280</width><height>720</height><tags>made right, romans, we are family, brent sellers, romans 12, November 12</tags><embed_privacy>anywhere</embed_privacy></video><video><id>31739785</id><title>It Starts With A Girl</title><description>The Girls At Risk school in Niger, Africa provides a future for girls through training, education, and a community. Watch this documentary on how Girls At Risk is providing girls with a new-found life and hope.</description><url>http://vimeo.com/31739785</url><upload_date>2011-11-07 12:44:25</upload_date><mobile_url>http://vimeo.com/m/31739785</mobile_url><thumbnail_small>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/214/094/214094295_100.jpg</thumbnail_small><thumbnail_medium>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/214/094/214094295_200.jpg</thumbnail_medium><thumbnail_large>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/214/094/214094295_640.jpg</thumbnail_large><user_name>RockPointe Church</user_name><user_url>http://vimeo.com/rockpointe</user_url><user_portrait_small>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ps/196/827/1968276_30.jpg</user_portrait_small><user_portrait_medium>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ps/196/827/1968276_75.jpg</user_portrait_medium><user_portrait_large>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ps/196/827/1968276_100.jpg</user_portrait_large><user_portrait_huge>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ps/196/827/1968276_300.jpg</user_portrait_huge><stats_number_of_likes>0</stats_number_of_likes><stats_number_of_plays>27</stats_number_of_plays><stats_number_of_comments>0</stats_number_of_comments><duration>385</duration><width>1280</width><height>720</height><tags>girls at risk, niger, africa</tags><embed_privacy>anywhere</embed_privacy></video><video><id>31738299</id><title>Why Should We Go On Missions?</title><description>A short video on the benefits of going on a short term mission, and how God provides opportunities for us to grow through missions.</description><url>http://vimeo.com/31738299</url><upload_date>2011-11-07 12:19:29</upload_date><mobile_url>http://vimeo.com/m/31738299</mobile_url><thumbnail_small>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/214/083/214083217_100.jpg</thumbnail_small><thumbnail_medium>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/214/083/214083217_200.jpg</thumbnail_medium><thumbnail_large>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/214/083/214083217_640.jpg</thumbnail_large><user_name>RockPointe Church</user_name><user_url>http://vimeo.com/rockpointe</user_url><user_portrait_small>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ps/196/827/1968276_30.jpg</user_portrait_small><user_portrait_medium>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ps/196/827/1968276_75.jpg</user_portrait_medium><user_portrait_large>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ps/196/827/1968276_100.jpg</user_portrait_large><user_portrait_huge>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ps/196/827/1968276_300.jpg</user_portrait_huge><stats_number_of_likes>0</stats_number_of_likes><stats_number_of_plays>18</stats_number_of_plays><stats_number_of_comments>0</stats_number_of_comments><duration>256</duration><width>1280</width><height>720</height><tags>missions</tags><embed_privacy>anywhere</embed_privacy></video><video><id>31735476</id><title>Made Right - Romans: Good News for Everyone</title><description>Series: Made Right - Romans&lt;br /&gt;
Sermon: Good News for Everyone&lt;br /&gt;
Speaker: Dennis &amp; Dorrie Hansen, and Rebecca Trask&lt;br /&gt;
Scripture: Romans 10&lt;br /&gt;
Date: November 6, 2011&lt;br /&gt;
&lt;br /&gt;
The BIG idea: Nothing can separate us from the love of God. &lt;br /&gt;
It is this truth that motivates an urgency for mission.</description><url>http://vimeo.com/31735476</url><upload_date>2011-11-07 11:33:06</upload_date><mobile_url>http://vimeo.com/m/31735476</mobile_url><thumbnail_small>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/214/063/214063669_100.jpg</thumbnail_small><thumbnail_medium>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/214/063/214063669_200.jpg</thumbnail_medium><thumbnail_large>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/214/063/214063669_640.jpg</thumbnail_large><user_name>RockPointe Church</user_name><user_url>http://vimeo.com/rockpointe</user_url><user_portrait_small>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ps/196/827/1968276_30.jpg</user_portrait_small><user_portrait_medium>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ps/196/827/1968276_75.jpg</user_portrait_medium><user_portrait_large>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ps/196/827/1968276_100.jpg</user_portrait_large><user_portrait_huge>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ps/196/827/1968276_300.jpg</user_portrait_huge><stats_number_of_likes>0</stats_number_of_likes><stats_number_of_plays>76</stats_number_of_plays><stats_number_of_comments>0</stats_number_of_comments><duration>2396</duration><width>1280</width><height>720</height><tags>Made right, romans, Good news for everyone, missions, Dennis hansen, dorrie hansen, rebecca trask, romans 10, November 6</tags><embed_privacy>anywhere</embed_privacy></video><video><id>31379429</id><title>Made Right - Romans: Life Through the Spirit</title><description>Series: Made Right - Romans&lt;br /&gt;
Sermon: Life Through the Spirit&lt;br /&gt;
Speaker: Ron Gray&lt;br /&gt;
Scripture: Romans 8&lt;br /&gt;
Date: October 30, 2011</description><url>http://vimeo.com/31379429</url><upload_date>2011-10-31 11:36:34</upload_date><mobile_url>http://vimeo.com/m/31379429</mobile_url><thumbnail_small>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/211/425/211425953_100.jpg</thumbnail_small><thumbnail_medium>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/211/425/211425953_200.jpg</thumbnail_medium><thumbnail_large>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/211/425/211425953_640.jpg</thumbnail_large><user_name>RockPointe Church</user_name><user_url>http://vimeo.com/rockpointe</user_url><user_portrait_small>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ps/196/827/1968276_30.jpg</user_portrait_small><user_portrait_medium>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ps/196/827/1968276_75.jpg</user_portrait_medium><user_portrait_large>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ps/196/827/1968276_100.jpg</user_portrait_large><user_portrait_huge>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ps/196/827/1968276_300.jpg</user_portrait_huge><stats_number_of_likes>0</stats_number_of_likes><stats_number_of_plays>57</stats_number_of_plays><stats_number_of_comments>0</stats_number_of_comments><duration>1949</duration><width>1280</width><height>720</height><tags>Romans, Made Right, Life Through the Spirit, Ron Gray, October 30</tags><embed_privacy>anywhere</embed_privacy></video><video><id>31041561</id><title>Mark Mittelberg - 20 Reasons You Can Be Confident Christianity Is True</title><description>Mark Mittelberg gives us a powerful and encouraging seminar on &quot;20 Reasons You Can Be Confident Christianity Is True&quot;. This is for anyone (even the skeptics) with questions on Christianity.</description><url>http://vimeo.com/31041561</url><upload_date>2011-10-24 14:50:13</upload_date><mobile_url>http://vimeo.com/m/31041561</mobile_url><thumbnail_small>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/208/872/208872031_100.jpg</thumbnail_small><thumbnail_medium>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/208/872/208872031_200.jpg</thumbnail_medium><thumbnail_large>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/208/872/208872031_640.jpg</thumbnail_large><user_name>RockPointe Church</user_name><user_url>http://vimeo.com/rockpointe</user_url><user_portrait_small>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ps/196/827/1968276_30.jpg</user_portrait_small><user_portrait_medium>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ps/196/827/1968276_75.jpg</user_portrait_medium><user_portrait_large>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ps/196/827/1968276_100.jpg</user_portrait_large><user_portrait_huge>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ps/196/827/1968276_300.jpg</user_portrait_huge><stats_number_of_likes>0</stats_number_of_likes><stats_number_of_plays>217</stats_number_of_plays><stats_number_of_comments>0</stats_number_of_comments><duration>5726</duration><width>1280</width><height>720</height><tags>Mark Mittelberg, Christianity is true</tags><embed_privacy>anywhere</embed_privacy></video></videos>
```

Comment: What does the data passed to serializedString look like?

Comment: I edited the question to include the contents of the `serializedString` parameter.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744334/the-quest-for-0x0b

Comment: No, I looked there. For starters, I can't find `&#xB` in my serialized string, and secondly, he's not saying how he deserialized the string. FWIW, it's Vimeo that's doing the serialization, not my own code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XML you posted looks fine; you either "hacked out" the character that is causing the problem, or you posted a sanitized version of `serializedString`.

XML is required to contain only printable characters, and 0x0B is not printable, so your `serXml.Deserialize` is doing the right thing. You have to find the non-printable characters and decide what to do with them. Something like:

```
using (var sr = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(serializedString)))
{
    int line = 0;
    string s;
    while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        line++;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
        {
            char c = s[i];
            if (char.IsControl(c))
                Console.WriteLine("Line " + line + ", char " + i + " is invalid char " + (int)c);
        }
    }
}
```

will show what characters of `serializedString` are bad. Whatever you're getting `serializedString` from has to be fixed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm getting the `serializedString` from Vimeo. I would have assumed that they had these things worked out. Also, the compiler is failing on your `sr.ReadLine()`

Comment: I found the error in this portion of the string above `BIG IDEA:God` Everywhere it's displayed in the browser, it looks exactly like that, however, when pasted into an editor (I use Webstorm) it looks like this `BIG IDEA: God`... The character between the `:` and the `G` is where it's failing... I even ran the XML through a validator to confirm.

Comment: would have looked better in the above comment if the string didn't break across the line: `BIG IDEA: God`

Comment: The devs over at Vimeo are fixing the serialization so that I have clean data to work with.